# Passing a record to postgres procedure from psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have written a postgres procedure which takes a record as an input

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.foo(
    file_record record)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
DECLARE
    ...;
BEGIN
    ...;
END;
$$
```

In python I am then using a cursor to make a query which reads a record from another table and I would like to pass this record to the `public.foo` procedure.

How can I accomplish this?

My current approach was this:

```
rdCur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=extras.RealDictCursor)
rdCur.execute(<some sql query>)

rdCur2 = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=extras.RealDictCursor)
sql_query2 = 'CALL public.foo(%s);

for record in rdCur:
    rdCur2.execute(sql_query2, record)
```

but unfortunately this does not work. I also tried `extras.execute_values` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Define not work? In other words what is the error returned? Though I'm going to guess it has to do with passing a `dict` in as `record`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver with execute I get the message `.... in execute return super(RealDictCursor, self).execute(query, vars) KeyError: 0` 

for execute_values I get `... in execute_values  parts.append(cur.mogrify(template, args)) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: The underling issue is you are passing a `dict` to a single parameter. I don't have time now to run up a test case, but I'm guessing you will need to use a default cursor that returns tuples and use [Tuple Adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that I should try to pass a `namedtuple` instead of a `RealDictRow` returned by the `RealDictCursor`?

Comment: I now tried using a `NamedTupleCursor` but this also gives me an error. I fail to see how a regular cursor which returns tuples could be used since the input to the procedure expects a record and records have dict like properties where you can access 'sub variables' by name.

Comment: you just need to pass a standard tuple to `rdCur2` for the `record` value so something like `rdCur2.execute(sql_query2, ("fizz", )`

Comment: This will be easier to solve if you provide more information in your question: 1) How are you using the function in `psql`? 2) When saying things like '...also gives me an error', it is a good idea to also include the error message.